# Making Licence File

Tags: c#

Im working on making licence file that looks like that:

```
<Licence>
    <NUMBER>123124124</NUMBER>
    <SERIAL>JKP231234</SERIAL>
</Licence>
<Licence>
    <NUMBER>123124124</NUMBER>
    <SERIAL>JKP231234</SERIAL>
</Licence>
<Licence>
    <NUMBER>123124124</NUMBER>
    <SERIAL>JKP231234</SERIAL>
</Licence>
<Licence>
    <NUMBER>123124124</NUMBER>
    <SERIAL>JKP231234</SERIAL>
</Licence>

<Signature>AFSDGARTYSDFH346347DFHQYADFHDSZJWSDFBSART</Signature>
```

It will be desktop app that works with client ERP system. System has 2 numbers that are unique (both in ). 
I want to generate licence and sen it to client. This is my approach, on my machine:

1. I hash licence (MD5)
2. I encrypt hash with my Private key (output is in licence file )
3. I send licence file to client.

In my app on client side:

4. I decrypt  with hard coded public key.
5. I make hash of licence
6. I compare counted hash with hash in 'signature'

If its ok i then check system number and serial. If its not correct (someone changed numbers) i pop error licence message.

Is my approach correct ? I mean it making licence that way a good practice ?

P.S. I hope i described it good enough.

Comment: An Asymmetric SHA hash would be better than MD5, but there is alikely much more you want to hash: product-version so a license applies to a product version and not universally.  Not sure what you are up to, but so far it looks like anyone who copies that file to their machine will pass.  Licensing and copy protection is complex (and a bit pointless); if it is worth protecting subscribe to a service.

Comment: About copying its fine. My app works with ERP system, that has unique number.

Comment: Well, if the client-side is able to *successfully* decrypt the license-information using the public key, **that, alone** is "good enough." You don't need to fool-around with hashes: you can merely use plain text values in the "payload." Either the payload is successfully decrypted, or it is not. Only you, the possessor of the secret private-key, could have generated such a ciphertext. The public-key algorithm should be able to tell your application whether the decrypt was successful. ("Keep it *simple,* 'cuz you're gonna be the one to *debug* it!") **:-D**